# Installing java on Docker php:7.1-apache-stretch

Tags: java, php, docker, dockerfile

Been slamming this docker config file for a few hours now and am starting to conclude this is impossible. Help me change my mind!

I'm trying to install open-jdk in a docker image like so:

```
FROM php:7.1-apache-stretch
# NOTE: We cannot upgrade to 7.2+ until we remove all uses of mcrypt. It 
is officially removed.

RUN echo 'deb http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-backports main' > 
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/backports.list
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y stretch-backports
RUN apt-get install -y default-jdk-headless ca-certificates-java
```

And get the following error:

```
E: Unable to locate package stretch-backports
ERROR: Service 'app' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get     
install -y stretch-backports' returned a non-zero code: 100
```

Comment: Could you try build your image up to "RUN apt-get update" (comment the rest of the file). Then, create the container and connect to the bash. Try there "apt-get install -y stretch-backports" to see what error are you getting exactly.

Answer (score 1):

Success! I was able to resolve by following this:

https://assertnull.com/installing-java-in-docker-php/

Here's my dockerfile now:

```
FROM php:7.1-apache-stretch
# NOTE: We cannot upgrade to 7.2+ until we remove all uses of mcrypt. It is officially removed.

# Hack for debian-slim to make the jdk install work below.
RUN mkdir -p /usr/share/man/man1

# repo needed for jdk install below.
RUN echo 'deb http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-backports main' > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/backports.list

# Update image & install application dependant packages.
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
nano \
libxext6 \
libfreetype6-dev \
libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
libpng-dev \
libmcrypt-dev \
libxslt-dev \
libpcre3-dev \
libxrender1 \
libfontconfig \
uuid-dev \
ghostscript \
curl \
wget \
ca-certificates-java

RUN apt-get -t stretch-backports install -y default-jdk-headless
```